# rename files with '$'\374'' on bash

Tags: bash, replace, rename, filenames, file-rename

I have multiple files from a defect usb-stick. Many of them have the "._" from Mac OS in the beginning, which should be kept. Some files have substitues for the german ä, ö or ü which are shown on the bash (ls -al) like:

> 'Pr'$'\374''fung_File.pdf'

How can I remove the '$'\374''? I have tried:

```
rename -n 's/\\'/_/g' *
```

which does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ls`'s output is a bit misleading, your files don't really have quotes or dollar signs in their names. Try:

```
rename -n 's/\374/_/' *
```

remove -n if its output looks good.

Comment: One more question please. I just saw, that the above mentioned "374" is just one of a long row of different 3 digit numbers (304, 366... you name it). is there a way to "mask" them? I've tried a "?", but that didn't worked...

Comment: I've tried it with rename -n 's/\[0-9][0-9][0-9]/_/' * but it doesn't work my understanding of regular expressions is not nearly well enough. I also need to change filenames like "Test(file).txt" to "Testfile.txt". Therefor i've tried rename -n 's/\(//' * for the starting "(", didn't worked. :-(

Comment: @NoName Those *3 digit numbers* are octal representations of non-printable characters, like `\374` is a single character, `[0-9][0-9][0-9]` won't match them. You can try `s/[^[:print:]]/_/g` or something like that, refer to https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html for detailed information about character classes.